# How to add random noise to the labels using DNNLinearCombinedClassifier for tf1.15?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

Currently, I am working with the wide and deep classifier in tf1.15 (DNNLinearCombinedClassifier), and defined the following function to add random noise to the labels:

```
def add_random_noise(labels):
    labels = tf.dtypes.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    rnd_noise = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))
    return tf.add(labels, tf.math.multiply_no_nan(0.05, rnd_noise))
```

This function is then applied to the dataset using `map` and applied only to the target column. However when I train my model, it generates the following output:

```
(0) Invalid argument: assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (head/labels:0) = ] [[0.00486446638][0.0133116841][0.0143840136]...] [y (head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
```

As far as I understand, `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` is calculating the number of unique values in target and generated the error due to the difference between n_classes and the number of unique values. I reviewed the documentation of `DNNLinearCombinedEstimator`, but it uses MSE as loss, and I would definetely like to train my model using cross entropy as it is done in `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`. I would like to ask you if there is a way to use wide and deep classifier with this *perturbed* label column and cross entropy as my training loss function.